# obtener el texto de un elemento(td) con javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, eventos

tengo una duda como obtener el valor de un elemento(el texto dentro de este) ya que al parecer no lo logro con .value, .innerHTML, textContent y ahora pensaba hacerlo con target..pero no lo soluciono..alguien podria ayudarme..saludos y gracias

```js
document.getElementById("mano1").addEventListener("click",saludar);
document.getElementById("mano2").addEventListener("click",saludar);

      function saludar(e){
        alert("haz pulzado el tr"+ e.target.??);
      }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="mano1">hola mundo1</tr>
    <tr id="mano2">hola mundo2</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` y `textContent` te servirían para lo que quieres hacer, `value` y `target` son para cosas distintas pero tu problema eran otros errores en el código que los explica @Kiko_L en su respuesta. Como te han dicho también puedes usar `innerText`, hay algunas diferencias entre esas tres propiedades pero para tu ejemplo todas te sirven igual.

Comment: te doy las gracias por tomarse el tiempo para ayudarme en este problema..y es verdad que tenia varios errores en el html y js...solo que no quise dejarlos al 100% porque crei que solo les serviria de una pequeña referencia a lo que quiero hacer..soy nuevo usando este sitio de ayuda que aun no lo logro dominar..pero en fin gracias de nuevo y revisare el codigo para resolver mi problema..gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varias cosas:

1. HTML: Debes crear bien tu `HTML`. Fíjate que tienes el `<head>` sin cerrar, no has creado el tag `<table>` para contener tus `<tr>` y además, te faltan los `<td>` dentro de los `<tr>`
2. Dentro de tu JS tienes esto que es incorrecto: `.??` (de hecho en tu ejemplo da error)
3. La función `saludar` tiene un parámetro `e` que no le estás pasando en el `addEventListener`
4. Dicha llamada a la función `saludar` tienes que pasarla por referencia en un `function(){}` si no quieres que se invoque inmediatamente. Lo que quieres es pasar esa referencia a la función y sólo invocarla cuando hagan clic.
5. Para obtener el valor contenido en tu `<td>` puedes utilizar [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando.

```js
document.getElementById("mano1").addEventListener("click",function(){saludar(this)});
document.getElementById("mano2").addEventListener("click",function(){saludar(this)});

function saludar(e){      
  console.log("Has pulsado el tr: "+ e.innerText);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<table>
    <tr id="mano1"><td>Hola mundo 1</td></tr>
    <tr id="mano2"><td>Hola mundo 2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aquí otro utilizando [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind)

```js
let el1 = document.getElementById("mano1");
el1.addEventListener("click",saludar.bind(null,el1));
let el2 = document.getElementById("mano2");
el2.addEventListener("click",saludar.bind(null,el2));

function saludar(e){   
  console.log("Has pulsado el tr: "+ e.innerText);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body id="body">
<table>
    <tr id="mano1"><td>Hola mundo 1</td></tr>
    <tr id="mano2"><td>Hola mundo 2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: les doy las gracias por tomarse el tiempo para ayudarme en este problema..y es verdad que tenia varios errores en el html y js...solo que no quise dejarlos al 100% porque crei que solo les serviria de una pequeña referencia a lo que quiero hacer..soy nuevo usando este sitio de ayuda que aun no lo logro dominar..pero en fin gracias de nuevo y revisare el codigo para resolver mi problema..gracias a todos!!!